# How to set the EEVEE render image output to match the size of the Camera Viewport and Cycles Render Size

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene with an animated camera fly thru. When i render the CYCLES version it shows the full screen you see in the photo (the camera viewport) when i render with EEVEE it only renders what is in the Yellow Bounding Box in the image below. How can i get EEVEE render size match the CYCLCES render size

[image: camera viewport]

Comment: What do you see if you press 0 (zero) on the numpad? That should show you the view from the camera. It would also be helpful if you could show an image of Blender's complete window with the outliner and Output properties in the R/H panel (printer icon). You're also in Material Preview mode rather than Rendered mode.

Comment: @JohnEason The yellow border already is the camera's field of view. You can see it in the top left of the viewport because it says "Camera Panoramic" - not "User Perspective" or "Right (or any other direction) Orthographic". And the issue can be seen there as well, it says "Camera Panoramic", not "Camera Perspective".

Answer (score 0):

The yellow box is the actual field of view of the camera given a specific *Focal Length* when using a *Perspective Camera*. But you have set up a *Panoramic Camera* - this only works in *Cycles*. The *Material Preview* uses *Eevee* for display, so in this mode you see the field of view of a camera with the *Focal Length* which is set when you switch the camera back to *Perspective* - which is the same *Eevee* will use for the finale render since it cannot render with a *Panoramic Camera*.

So here is a comparison. First we have the default *Perspective Camera*. As you can see, the field of view is the same no matter if you are in *Material Preview* or in *Rendered View*, and pretty much no difference between *Cycles* and *Eevee*.

[image: perspective camera]

However, if you now change the camera to a *Panoramic Camera*, the field of view is much different in *Cycles*, whereas the *Material Preview* and the *Eevee* look as they did before. That's because the *Panoramic Camera* only works in *Cycles* and is the effect is only visible in *Rendered View*. You can even tell *Eevee* will show the "normal" *Perspective Camera* view, because when you look at the camera settings you will see that there is a *Panorama Type* option in *Cycles*, but in *Eevee* (although it says *Perspective* for the *Lens Type*) you can only set a *Focal Length* which by default is the one you had set before.

[image: panoramic camera]

But after all, your question was not only why it is different but how to match the field of view in *Eevee* to the one in *Cycles*. To cut it short, you cannot. The only thing you can do is use a *Perspective Camera* with a very very short *Focal Length* to widen your field of view, but it will not be the same as a *Panoramic Camera*. But as long as you use the *Perspective Camera*, the *Focal Length* will look the same in both *Cycles* and *Eevee*.

I've seen explanations how to create panoramic views in Eevee, but these are more like tricks involving multiple cameras etc. so you cannot simply switch from *Cycles* to *Eevee* and back and have the same field of view.